# how to write in to file in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm writting a plugin and there is an option to write css from admin side. Here I need to write css in to a specific file named style.css. For these i have used the php function `<?php file_put_contents($file, $data, FILE_TEXT )?>`. But it shows error like

> file_put_contents(http://localhost/car/wp-content/plugins/networks-inv/tab/style.css) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections in C:\wamp\www\car\wp-content\plugins\networks-inv\admin\templates.php on line 49. I cant understand why these errors shows?. Is there any method to write a file in wordpress plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write the System Path of the file ,not the URL.

You should :

```
$file = "car/wp-content/plugins/networks-inv/tab/style.css";
file_put_contents($file, $data, FILE_TEXT );
```

Comment: i have done with this, still it shows the warning, Warning: file_put_contents(wp-content/plugins/networks-inv/tab/style.css) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\car\wp-content\plugins\networks-inv\admin\templates.php on line 49

Comment: @user1295167 than try to find the correct file path ,and put it on $file because i can't find it out on you're Server ,as i wrote the issue is with the URI instead of System File Path ,the other part is you re's .

Comment: by using the given code, i can get the content from the css, file_get_contents("http://localhost/anwar/car/wp-content/plugins/networks-inv/tab/style.css"); why the write operation only shows the error?.

Comment: Because these 2 function's are completely different ,file_get_contents(); can fetch Raw Data from HTTP:// Streams while file_put_contents(); cannot.

Comment: i had done with the correct path, it shows the writing status true... But file doesn't shows any updations in file

Comment: Now you have a Permission Issue ,you should give you're PHP Script permission to write into that File.

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically fetch the plugin directory path by using the following WP function and then pass it into the `file_put_contents` function.

```
$upload_dir = plugin_dir_path( __DIR__ ).'/networks-inv/tab/style.css';
 
file_put_contents($upload_dir, $data, FILE_TEXT );
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be because you are trying to write using a http method try using local file paths instead

Answer (score 0):

I initially received the same warning, but determined cause to be setting file path as:

```
$file = ".\wp-content\plugins\logging.txt";
```

instead of

```
$file = ".\\\\wp-content\\\\plugins\\\\logging.txt";
```

File path should have two slashes instead of one.

I hope this resolves the problem of the incorrect path name.

Comment: I guess he can just use the constant WP_PLUGIN_DIR to pull up the plugin path?

Comment: if you're using different OSes (win, nix etc), you can replace the slashes with `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`  - see also https://www.php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php